# Difference between dofile and -l in lua

Tags: lua

In reading about the interpreter ive tried both dofile and -l to load files.
However -l only works like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J4Cx.png)

and dofile only works after typing lua into the cmd, what is the reason for this?

Comment: `-l` is a `lua` command option. `dofile` is a Lua function. I'm not sure how you're expecting them to work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`dofile` is a Lua function. You have to "type lua into the cmd" because you cannot run Lua functions in the Windows command line. You have to start the Lua interpreter first.

`lua -l name` only works like this becasue `-l`  is a command line option.

that will call `require("name")` as soon as the Lua interpreter started.

`dofile` and `require` are two different things btw.

Please read the manual

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate your response!